# Flashing buttons (C with GTK+)

Tags: css, c, button, gtk, gtk3

I changed color of buttons using css, but when I move the mouse over them, buttons change their color to the default for a moment.
"button:hover" and "button:active" didn't help.

Comment: Not at all clear what you're asking. If the problem is with a C program, how does CSS styling have anything to do with it? If the problem is with an HTML application, why is it tagged 'C'?

Comment: @Mark Benningfield : The GTK+ toolkit has a theming engine that allows to theme a user interface using CSS (since GTK+ 3).

Comment: @liberforce: Okay, thanks, that makes much more sense now. I hadn't messed with GTK+ in quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

I used both:

```
background-image: image(black);
background-color: black;
```

And now it works great.